# Vuex async methods ignore return resolve value

Tags: vue.js, promise, async-await, vuex, nuxt.js

So, I'm doing a rewritte of my first vuejs project to nuxtjs and I'm rewriting all my api calls to be store actions, when I noticed that I cannot return values from them, unless I reject them.

No matter how I try to return a value, `return x` or `return Promise.resolve(x)` my promise's result is always undefined

I tried the following simple action:

```
async uselessWait(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    return ("success"); // and return Promise.resolve("success");
  }, 1000)
}
```

and when calling it the result is always `undefined`, although the promise resolves normally

Is that intentional, is it a bug or is it just me?

Comment: Why do you need to return values from Vuex actions? I don't think it's a good practice. Why not to use Vue store instead?

Comment: TBH I do not **need** to return values, I just find it more clean e.g. to send the success message of an api call through the return, than coding a store value and upon resolving having the component read that stored value

Comment: If you check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise, it turns out that you should return a new instance of Promise like new Promise((resolve, reject) => {}) and not just Promise.resolve, could you try this?

Comment: @MátéWiszt apparently setting up from the start a `return new Promise()` works... But only if I do it before calling any async functions, which complicates things a bit. Also it makes me wonder why `return Promise.reject("whatever") ` works fine, while `resolve("whatever")` doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return a resolved `Promise` immediately.

Ideally

```
async uselessWait(){
  return setTimeout(() => {
    return ("success"); // and return Promise.resolve("success");
  }, 1000)
}
```

But `setTimeout` does not return a promise, so you can't do that.

Here' a take on setTimeout that does.

```js
setTimeoutPromise = (fn, delay) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        const ret = fn()
        resolve(ret)
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e)
      }
    }, delay)
  })
}

setTimeoutPromise(() => {
  console.log('ok')
}, 1000)
```

So for your example.

```
async uselessWait(){
  return setTimeoutPromise(() => {
    return ("success"); // and return Promise.resolve("success");
  }, 1000)
}
```

Now the async function returns a promise that resolves (or rejects if your callback throws)

You could also await instead of returning.

```
async uselessWait(){
  await setTimeoutPromise(() => {
    return ("success"); // and return Promise.resolve("success");
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I get it, in order for me to return the `Promise.resolve()` I need to chain the promises from the get-go, not just calling functions that return a promise

Comment: async functions alway return a promise.  If you don't return one, a Promise.resolve() is returned by default.  The awaits are really just chaining in a way, returning values instead of sending them to the next 'then'

Comment: If that is the case, shouldn't any return inside an async function return the value inside as a result?

Comment: yes, a value, or another promise. The return of the async is the same as.the value that would be sent into resolve, and an exception the same as calling reject.

Comment: Then why does my original function not return the value?

Comment: It is returning Promise.resolve(undefined) because you are not returning anything.    What you return in setTimeout has nothing to do with the return of the uselessWait function.  I might as well not be there are in in regards to program flow, it does not block.  If you don't use the function I suggested, you could simple return a promise from uselessWait, set the timeout in the promise, and then instead of returning from the timeout, call resolve on the promise that wraps it.